# Running program in .profile slows down GUI startx

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, bash

I want to run a python program that polls the keyboard on startup/login to my raspberry pi.

Previous attempts included cron jobs (failed due to lack of stdin or stdout).

`rc.local` also failed as it has no stdin (it got stuck in a perpetual loop - now *that* was fun to escape)

Hence I've arrived at placing my command into the .profile, and this appears to work well! The program functions exactly as intended when the Pi is turned on *but*...

When I then try to launch the GUI by `startx`, the screen turns black and completely fails to launch. It seems to be something to do with the Ppython program, because when I remove it from the `bash` .profile, it all functions fine.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

**Update**

I created a script that also output to LED's (a simple Red-Yellow-Green sequence) and it appears that .profile is execute *again* when `startx` is run? If so why?

Below is my .profile code, and then my python program

**.profile lines**

```
echo "About to run keyboard polling"; sleep 3
python /home/pi/poll_keyboard.py
```

**poll_keyboard.py**

```
import thread
import time
def input_thread(L):
    key = raw_input()
    L.append(key)
    thread.exit() #Should close thread at end
def do_print():
    L = []
    thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (L,))
    i = 0
    while True:
        print "Hello World %d" % i
        if L: #If anything has been detected
            break
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return L
key = do_print()
print "Key press detected: %s. Exiting in 2" % key
time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

Comment: You could try to add `&`: `python /home/pi/poll_keyboard.py &` this sends the python process in background, allowing the .profile script to continue

Comment: But would it still receive input from the keyboard?

Comment: Yes it should, since the process continues to run in the background

Comment: I've tried this - unfortunately it doesnt work - although stdout still goes to the console, neither input nor even Ctrl-C are linked back to the process - so it runs perpetually

Comment: The `.profile` is executed each time you login, regardless if it was via local console, ssh, GUI, …. You may try to prevent several parallel instances by checking if the script already runs. With a PID file, or with IPC (sockets, dbus, …). The `thread` module is deprecated by the way. `threading` exists many years as replacement. It also contains things like `Event` to wait for something in another thread without busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should only run that if the shell is interactive

```
test -t 0 && {
    echo "About to run keyboard polling"; sleep 3
    python /home/pi/poll_keyboard.py
}
```

Second, Xorg intercepts your keyboard codes using Xorg drivers (likely the `evdev` driver in this case).  This is why you cannot log the key with `raw_input()` and I would not be surprised if Xorg is not working either.

Keep in mind that you are not logging the "keyboard" in your python code.  Instead, you are reading the processes `stdin` (fd=0).  If that is hooked to a tty, then you are kind of logging the keyboard but even then you are likely getting `cooked` input anyway.